# How to read arrays in Json using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a Json data as listed below:

```
var x = {

"array1":"['x1','x2']",
"array2":"['a1', 'a2']"
}
```

I need to print the individual elements of the array as below

```
x1
x2
a1
a2
```

When I do `var y = JSON.parse(x)`, it gives me `"Unexpected token o"`

It seems to be coming from the ***JSON.parse*** line. If I do `x = '["x1", "x2"]',` there is no error but I need to have two  arrays in the **JSON.** So how do I read them

Thanks for any answers

Comment: Unless you're getting this data from somewhere else, *it shouldn't be JSON*. Just make a normal object. You don't need JSON in your own code!

Answer (score 4):

That is not JSON. JSON is a string and not an object hence its abbreviation of **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation. What you have is colloquially referred to as a POJO or **P**lain **O**ld **J**avaScript **O**bject. They are different. The former is a data exchange format similar to YAML or XML while the latter is an actual object with properties and values.

Your POJO does have JSON values but since it is already an object you can't use `JSON.parse` to parse the entire object. That is where the "o" is coming from in the error message. `JSON.parse` will coerce the first argument to a string if it is not a string:

```
var foo = {};
JSON.parse(foo); // is essentially doing this foo.toString() which is "[object Object]"
JSON.parse('{}'); // This would parse to an empty object though since it is a string
```

So now when it attempts to parse "[object Object]" it sees what may be an array but then encounters a character that hasn't been quoted, the "o" in "object", and therefore throws an error.

For your example to be JSON you would need to write it as:

```js
var json = '{"array1":["x1","x2"],"array2":["a1","a2"]}';
var x = JSON.parse(json);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(x, null, 4) + '</pre>');
```

And so, now that we have a real JSON value we can answer your original question:

```js
var json = '{"array1":["x1","x2"],"array2":["a1","a2"]}';
var x = JSON.parse(json);

var vals = Object.keys(x).sort().reduce(function (arr, key) {
  arr = arr.concat(x[key]);
  return arr;
}, []).join('\n');

document.write('<pre>' + vals + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your JSON should be like the following

```
{
  "array1": ["x1", "x2"],
  "array2": ["a1", "a2"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your array in many different ways - two examples

```
var x = [{array1:['x1','x2']},{array2:['a1','a2']}]
x[1].array2 produces ["a1", "a2"]
x[1].array2[0] produces "a1"

var xx = {array1:['x1','x2'],array2:['a1','a2']}
xx.array2 produces ["a1", "a2"]
xx.array2[0] produces "a1"
```

third example

```
var xxx = {array1:{x1:'x1',x2:'x2'},array2:{a1:'a1',a2:'a2'}}
xxx.array1.x1 produces "x1"
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have there, that 'x' variable `var x = {"array1":[...]...}` is already a javascript object, so you can simply pass through the object keys and display the values.

Given 'x' as the object you can have something like:

```
var key,       
    result = '';

for (key in x) { 
    if (x.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        result = result + x[key].join('\n') + '\n';
    }
}
// There you have the result...
```

As John said earlier, for JSON.parse() you wold need a string as a parameter to be able to parse it into a javascript object.

Answer (score -1):

so, you can use this script to do that (correct json too - http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ -, don't know why this downrate.....i guess a noob didnt realize :D):

```
var x = {
 "array1": ["x1", "x2"],
 "array2": ["a1", "a2"]
}

for (var key in x) {
 if (x.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
 document.getElementById("test").innerHTML += key + " -> " + x[key]+" <br>";
}
}
```

i've created a working fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/rjzzqLmr/1/